# What are non-functional quantitative requirements?

Tags: requirements

I got the following question for homework but I am confused on what is being asked. I'm not looking for you to give me the answers I am just wondering what non-functional quantitative requirements are? I thought non-functional requirements, such as as usability, maintainability, etc., were qualitative?

> Specify and comment on seven non-functional quantitative requirements for an e-commerce application. You should choose one sub-characteristic from each of the main characteristics [from ISO 9126].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quantative requirements are defined in terms of numerical values.

ISO9126 is a software quality model, which has the following characteristics:

- Functionality
- Reliability
- Usability
- Efficiency
- Maintainability
- Portability

Few examples:

**Efficiency.**

System must be able to handle 10,000 concurrent users.

**Usability**

System must be available in two languages: English and French.

Reference: http://www.sqa.net/iso9126.html

I can't believe they make people pay for this: http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=22749

Wish my homework was that interesting at a time. Good luck.

Comment: 10000 concurrent users is not scalibility? maybe being able to handle them within a time constraint makes it efficient.

Comment: Hi, scalability isn't a characteristics of a quality model, therefore I've put the requirement under efficiency. You can rephrase it to say: "System must be able to handle 10,000 concurrent users effectively."

Answer (score 1):

Non-functional requirements are defined with numbers. For example, a system cannot be down more than 6 hours in a year. This is a reliability non-functional requirement.